# How do I upload a file with metadata to jfrog artifactory with curl

Tags: rest, curl, artifactory

I upload a file like this:

```
curl -u ${CREDS} --upload-file ${file} ${url}
```

Is there a way to add a body or headers that will set some metadata for the file? Like build number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually deploy artifacts with properties to Artifactory OSS using [matrix parameters](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution), for example:

```
curl -uadmin:password -T file.tar "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/generic-local/file.tar;foo=bar;"
```

And get the artifact properties using REST API, for example:

```
curl -uadmin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/generic-local/file.tar?properties"
```

Viewing properties from the UI and other features are limited to the Pro edition.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a pro feature. Documentation: [Set Item Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

```
PUT /api/storage/{repoKey}{itemPath}?properties=p1=v1[,v2][|p2=v3][&recursive=1]
```

Not helping me :-/

Comment: I added an answer with a solution which works for Artifactory OSS